# How to load all list items using caml query?

Tags: list, document-library, csom, caml-query, caml

I'm using `SP 2013`. And I have a `Wiki Page Library`. I try to load all items from this list. I'm using the following code:

```
var context = new ClientContext("SiteUrl");
context.Load(context.Site);
context.ExecuteQuery();

var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Wiki Page Library");
context.Load(list, c=>c.ItemCount);
context.ExecuteQuery();

//it gives me actual items count
//in my case it's 9 items
//Home.aspx; About.aspx; Categories.aspx; Topic.aspx etc.
var itemsLength = list.ItemCount;

var camlQuery = @"<View Scope='All'><Query></Query></View>";
var query = new SP.CamlQuery { ViewXml = camlQuery };
var items = list.GetItems(query);
context.Load(items);
context.ExecuteQuery();
//it gives a wrong result
//only one in my case
var count =  items.ToArray().Length;
```

And I've also checked the following `caml` queries:
(but unfortunately it gives me the same result)

```
<View Scope="RecursiveAll">
    <Query>
    <QueryOptions>
        <ViewAttributes Scope="Recursive"/>
    </QueryOptions>
    </Query>
</View>

<View Scope="RecursiveAll">
    <Query>
    </Query>
</View>
```

And this is helpful
[image: And this is helpful]

Comment: can you try it as `var items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());` and check ?

Comment: @GautamSheth actually I did. Just see  `I've also checked the following caml queries:` section. The seconds query is exactly the same with `CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery()`

Answer (score 3):

Everything is fine with your query. Most likely it is related with  *files that were uploaded for the **first** time by another users but never checked in* (you could access those files by visiting `Library settings` and then `Manage files which have no checked in version` page)

[image]

Even though `List.ItemCount` returns all the items (including checked out ones), I'm afraid there is no way retrieve those items (or files) via CSOM/REST APIs until they checked in.

Comment: thanks for reply. but actually i see "All files currently have a checked in version". Basically it looks like redirect. I mean when I go to Wiki Page Library, SP redirects me to specific folder which was created automatically by SP during document library creation. I have no idea what feature/setting is it. Is it connected to web setting or to docLib settings. But no matter which document library i create SP creates the specific folder automatically. And when I try to go to this document library SP redirects me to this folder. So the same behavior with caml query. Can you help me ?

Comment: I can add some screenshots If you need. Just pm me.

Answer (score 1):

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Your List Title');
var items = list.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
context.load(items, 'Include(Field1, Field2, Field3)');
context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
  var en = factorItems.getEnumerator();
  while (en.moveNext()){
    var c = en.get_current();
    console.log(c.get_item('Field1'));//get field value
    console.log(c.get_fieldValues());//get object with {Field1: value1 ... etc}
  }
}, function(s,a){alert('Failed load, server says: ' + a.get_message())});
```

That's your basic interface. From there you can load them into an array or process them somehow. Hope it helps.

Comment: The code above is completely the same as mine. The problem is not all items will be selected. Wiki page library has specific items(Home.aspx) which won't be returned. Anyway thanks.